# Shiny application in server keeps crashing

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny application that runs on a cloud server. I don't get any error messages and my app session logs are clean. My app takes around 30 seconds to load....My assumption is: while the app is loading the user clicks on various input options in the page or tabs...which triggers multiple loads at the same time...that leads to the app crash.

When i say crash, it just goes dead.  I have to use command line to start the application again.

Is there any remedy to this?
Is there a way to restart shiny-server automatically when I get a message `Active: inactive(dead)`.